# Jquery scrolling on multiple hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I'm currently working on a singlepage website,
I choose to keep header and footer fixed and i got some trouble while using hyperlink hashtag.
I got 4 links to 4 parts of my page,

I want to display the content in the middle, like that i could avoid some datas hidden by both the header and footer.

I have found this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

I can't make it work for my own site.

I put as id

```
<a name="timeline" class="anchor_title"><center><h1>Our progress</h1></center></a>

<a name="map" class="anchor_title"><center><h1>Our gathering Data</h1></center></a>
```

Does anyone could explain me how i could for example catch the name of each hyperlink and place it on the jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you found would have to make us of the href attribute :

```
<a href="#timeline" class="anchor_title"><center><h1>Our progress</h1></center></a>

<a href="#map" class="anchor_title"><center><h1>Our gathering Data</h1></center></a>
```

Further in the HTML these links refer to elements with the same id :

```
<div id="timeline"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

In the script, the class will have to match the selector of the links :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.anchor_title').click(function(event) {     
event.preventDefault();
var offset = $(this.hash).offset().top-$('#header').height();
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: offset}, 500);
});
});
```

Note how the height of the (fixed) header is subtracted from the position it should scroll to, it will otherwise end up beneath it (at the top of the screen) instead of right below.

Edit - here's a basic example :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNZzNq

There are a few things to be noted about this :

For preventing animation buildup, the `stop()` method has been added to the function.

The first element on the page needs top padding (or alternatively a `:before` pseudo element) in the same amount as the height of the header to get it placed correctly with respect to the fixed position.

Special HTML5 elements `header` and `section` are being used in the markup of the example. The document itself needs the correct declaration for this : `<!DOCTYPE html>`. With any other type of declaration the elements would have to be converted to divs with a class defined :

```
<section id="first"></section>

section {height: 70vh}
```

Would become (along with a change of CSS) :

```
<div id="first" class="section"></div>

.section {height: 70vh}
```

Hope that solves it but let me know if it needs any other tweaks.

New edit - the HTML5 elements will make a bit of difference for the selector in the script as well!

```
$('#header').height()

$('header').height()
```

Comment: If I may add - I think the `<center>` tag is deprecated, might be better to use CSS.

Comment: While trying your jquery solution, an error throw saying that ($document) was not reconize. The thing is, normaly it's happen if jquery is not well load. Here i load it from  < src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"> and any other script is working well. I saw some article about $document which could fire too early, could it fire before the package is download ? 
If so how could i do to patch that ?

And by the way, thank you to remind me of center, i'm not use to that deprecated <center> attribute.

Comment: I didn't find a way to make it work so i tried JQuery(document) and no errors this time but i didn't see any changes. The thing is, my hyperlink are working, went i press i go to the link so it's that anchor_title is not perfom.

Comment: Okay, sorry about the error. It was a typo. In this case `$(document).ready` should generally work. There are no images loading or anything so using `$(window).on('load', function() { ... })` shouldn't be necessary. I'll have another look at it.

Comment: I've added a live example. Hope that helps to clear things up.